# Actual JSON serialization benchmark for Java-APIs

Tags: java, json, serialization, benchmarking

I'm looking for an benchmark for different serialization APIs. All I found are outdated Posts and Articles from a year and more before. So I'm hoping that anyone could share a link to an up to date benchmark?

PLEASE: I'm aware of the implementations you can find in the web. I don't want a recommendation for your preferred API. And I don't need a "I think it's fast". What I'm searching for is just an actual comparison of the performance in measured values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a one benchmark.

http://code.google.com/p/thrift-protobuf-compare/wiki/Benchmarking

In this article I discuss the importance of re-cycling objects to improve serialisation times.

http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2011/10/serialization-using-bytebuffer-and.html

IMHO: JSon is one of the most difficult formats to deserialise efficiently, even harder than XML.

Comment: The first I found, too. But it was last updated at `Apr 27, 2010`. The new page says `Benchmark results are currently unavailable and will be updated soon! - Last edited by scottostler, 3 months ago`. The second I dind't found but it's from `27th October 2011`.

Comment: A faster machine will give you better results (see the results I posted) but the relative difference is much the same.  You can run the benchmarks yourself.

Comment: But it is possible that a new Version of an API is much improved in performance. For that I asked for an actual benchmark. And I don't have the time to create and run it myself. But thank you anyway. If nobody can point to an actual one your answer will be accepted, because it's the latest I saw until now.

Comment: I don't get the impression these APIs are going through dramatic changes. They are all pretty stable.

Comment: I hope so. When I've decided which to use I don't want to switch to another in a few months. But while I'm figuring out, I like to rely on actual data.

Comment: You really need to test it for your data. The data structure used in the benchmark is short and simple and the results you get for your data could be completely different.

Comment: At this point of customer wishes and resulting design there only POJOs, so it's simple data without cycling or complex object structure. So I can rely on the simple tests. But thanks for the hint, I hold that in my mind when starting a project with more complexity.

Comment: I have found for text that a) using `double` instead of `int` can make a big difference b) creating objects like `String` can be relatively expensive.

Comment: For that I'm looking for an API which takes care of things like that. What I need is a fast, lightweight and easy to use API. Because of the simple data structure the configurability and extensionability doesn't matter. And with all the implementations around the net the performance is the fact I'm interested about. I could write my own serialization, but then I have to care about such differences you mentioned. An API which has good benchmark results shows that the developers had solved those problems.

Comment: It is often the case that the more general and easy to use an API, the slower it is. Getting the best speed often means doing only what your program needs and nothing else. i.e. customising it.

Comment: Marvin, all performance benchmarks that I have seen that are NOT done by authors of specific JSON library point to either Jackson being the fastest, or in some cases FastJSON (https://github.com/AlibabaTech/fastjson). Jvm-serializers benchmarks is not old -- code updates are done often (check mailing list archives, or join it). While result publishing is problematic (too long to explain here) running test locally is very easy. So just go and see your local numbers. You will find Jackson and FastJSON the fastest choices.

Answer (score 3):

Here are two recent ones as of last week.
It compares form byte[], reader, inputStream, char[], CharSequence, String, etc.

It compares Boon, Jackson, Smart JSON and GSON.

https://github.com/gatling/json-parsers-benchmark

https://github.com/RichardHightower/json-parsers-benchmark

Boon and Jackson are close on a few. At times Boon is 4x faster. Mostly Boon wins. :)
GSON is better than most at I/O, but Boon does best all around (and best at I/O), and it has an index overlay mode that is even faster (look at the second set.. the index overlay puts Boon way over the top).

https://github.com/RichardHightower/boon

I am bias. :)

But gatling is not, and the results are the same. Boon is wicked fast.

Comment: Is Boon still faster than Jackson now in 2021?